React native gets created but not running on windows 10. I have installed sdk tools and emulators using android studio
I am trying to install react native in my windows system. When I create app using following command:
npx react-native init MyApp
App folder gets created. But when I run this app using following command:
npx react-native run android, it fails with following exception

What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (E:\ReactNativeApps\App02\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-8c313250-1ca8-434c-88f6-83ace558c4e2) to immutable location (E:\ReactNativeApps\App02\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Could not move temporary workspace (E:\ReactNativeApps\App02\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-8c313250-1ca8-434c-88f6-83ace558c4e2) to immutable location (E:\ReactNativeApps\App02\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)```.

I have installed android studio with sdk platform and sdk tools. Can anyone please help?
